# Android network calls sometimes get stuck at IOException : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout

Tags: java, android, networking, okhttp

I have an app that uploads some files (png, mp4).
The full stack is Nginx + Node server behind it.
Sometimes, it seems that some users experience bizarre behavior in production when the internet is problematic, and then the Android app cannot send further Upload requests cause they all get :
`IOException : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout`.

However, the strangest thing is that we see the server does send a response (409 Conflict, meaning the files being uploaded already exist and done uploading), but the Android app simply doesn't get those responses and just keeps on trying to upload those files, but the connection keeps failing because of SocketTimeoutException every time again and again, instead of receiving the 409 response.

And then, after some time, it gets back to normal and suddenly can receive that 409 response and continue as if everything is fine.

I tried using the most basic HttpUrlConnection, as well as Square's OkHttp library, but it results in the same behavior.

When I debug it with Okhttp + HTTP/2 + a Proxy to monitor the requests, in the frame logging I see (with a Proxy enabled):

```
02-16 13:30:16.047  2719  6597 D okhttp.Http2: << 0x00000003     4 RST_STREAM    
02-16 13:30:16.049  2719  3758 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10117 canceled              : OkHttp ConnectionPool
02-16 13:30:16.051  2719  6597 D okhttp.Http2: >> 0x00000000     8 GOAWAY        
02-16 13:30:16.051  2719  6597 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10121 finished run in  60 s : <our server>
```

at this point my code already received an error from my server implementation. Then I see :

```
02-16 13:30:20.129  2719  3758 D okhttp.Http2: >> CONNECTION 505249202a20485454502f322e300d0a0d0a534d0d0a0d0a
02-16 13:30:20.131  2719  3758 D okhttp.Http2: >> 0x00000000     6 SETTINGS      
02-16 13:30:20.132  2719  3758 D okhttp.Http2: >> 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE 
02-16 13:30:20.133  2719  3758 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10157 scheduled after   0 µs: OkHttp <our server>
02-16 13:30:20.135  2719  3758 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10153 scheduled after   0 µs: OkHttp ConnectionPool
02-16 13:30:20.135  2719  7381 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10157 starting              : OkHttp <our server>
02-16 13:30:20.136  2719  7365 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10153 starting              : OkHttp ConnectionPool
02-16 13:30:20.137  2719  7365 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10153 run again after 300 s : OkHttp ConnectionPool
02-16 13:30:20.137  2719  7365 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10153 finished run in   1 ms: OkHttp ConnectionPool
02-16 13:30:20.138  2719  3758 D okhttp.Http2: >> 0x00000003  1063 HEADERS       END_HEADERS
02-16 13:30:20.145  2719  7381 D okhttp.Http2: << 0x00000000    18 SETTINGS      
02-16 13:30:20.146  2719  7381 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10154 scheduled after   0 µs: OkHttp <our server> applyAndAckSettings
02-16 13:30:20.147  2719  7381 D okhttp.Http2: << 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE 
02-16 13:30:20.147  2719  7365 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10154 starting              : OkHttp <our server> applyAndAckSettings
02-16 13:30:20.149  2719  7365 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10156 scheduled after   0 µs: OkHttp <our server> onSettings
02-16 13:30:20.151  2719  6597 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10156 starting              : OkHttp <our server> onSettings
02-16 13:30:20.151  2719  6597 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10156 finished run in   1 ms: OkHttp <our server> onSettings
02-16 13:30:20.152  2719  7365 D okhttp.Http2: >> 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
02-16 13:30:20.153  2719  3758 D okhttp.Http2: >> 0x00000003 65535 DATA          
02-16 13:30:20.153  2719  7365 D okhttp.TaskRunner: Q10154 finished run in   6 ms: OkHttp <our server> applyAndAckSettings
02-16 13:30:20.156  2719  3758 D okhttp.Http2: >> 0x00000003     1 DATA          
02-16 13:30:20.231  2719  7381 D okhttp.Http2: << 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
```

Following @Yuri Schimke's suggestion, I added PrintingEventListener, here's what I get :

```
2021-02-17 09:18:50.056 28203-28286/<package name> I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2021-02-17 09:18:53.378 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.000 callStart
2021-02-17 09:18:53.460 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.081 proxySelectStart
2021-02-17 09:18:53.462 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.084 proxySelectEnd
2021-02-17 09:18:53.462 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.084 dnsStart
2021-02-17 09:18:53.463 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.085 dnsEnd
2021-02-17 09:18:53.475 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.096 connectStart
2021-02-17 09:18:53.650 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.271 secureConnectStart
2021-02-17 09:18:53.796 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.418 secureConnectEnd
2021-02-17 09:18:53.834 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.456 connectEnd
2021-02-17 09:18:53.839 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.461 connectionAcquired
2021-02-17 09:18:53.870 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.492 requestHeadersStart
2021-02-17 09:18:53.891 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.513 requestHeadersEnd
2021-02-17 09:18:53.891 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 0.513 requestBodyStart
2021-02-17 09:19:03.382 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 10.003 requestFailed
2021-02-17 09:19:03.391 28203-28311/<package name>  I/System.out: 10.012 canceled
2021-02-17 09:19:03.399 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 10.021 connectionReleased
2021-02-17 09:19:03.400 28203-28286/<package name>  I/System.out: 10.022 callFailed
```

Comment: May be the first upload was interrupted by the bad network and afterwards the server returns on upload attempts only 409 because the file is still reserved by the interrupted upload. You should check what the server expects when the upload was interrupted (may be it implements some sort of resume)? Otherwise this may be a server bug not considering an network interruption on uoloads.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Robert. We tried checking the server, and we even added a Content-Length header containing the size of the file's byte array, so server side (nginx/backend) would know better whether the file was indeed fully uploaded.
Also, this bug doesn't happen on iOS, which basically ruled out the possibility of some bug on server side for us (though I'm not sure now anymore ..)
In addition to that, even if a request was interrupted by bad network, what do all the following requests produce IOException? it seems that the network layer on Android side get corrupted for some time

Comment: SocketTimeoutException usually means that the connection to the server has been established but no data was received within the specified socketTimeout. Make sure that value is not too short (e.g. 5000 millis or more). If it still happens may be there is a problem in the network system of Android when dealing with very bad network connections so that in the end the data connection is throttled to 0 bytes per second.

Comment: I see what you mean.. unfortunately setting higher timeouts seem to have no difference in this regard when it comes to the post requests. (by the way : the GET requests do work when the POST ones start getting the Exceptions).  So ultimately, in case the later scenario happens (problem in the network system of Android when dealing with bad network), are there really any solutions available that could at least mitigate the problem?

Comment: The timeout is on network level, hence if it makes a difference between GET and POST then there is something strange going on on the server. BTW: Are we talking about Wifi or mobile network connections going bad?

Comment: I might have understood, I meant I played with the `connection.setConnectTimeout(..)`, also tried readTimeout, and writeTimeout on okHttp ('write' doesn't exist by default with HttpUrlConnection).
GET requests do seem to be dependent on the given timeouts, but, for example the Upload requests seem to ignore any timeout setting like that (at least on the client side). 
Regarding the wifi vs mobile - for us, we've been testing this on Wifi (using Charles as a proxy to help us throttle the connection to test this bug), but I'm not 100% sure whether our clients used mobile network or wifi only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228749/discussion-between-bvtp-and-robert).

Comment: Is it possible the 409 is sent early, but the response isn't seen until the request finishes?

Comment: Why isn't Android using HTTP/2?

Comment: @YuriSchimke So, frankly, I'm not sure, we just noticed that the HttpUrlConnection we use , sends the requests in 1.1 and not 2 (unlike our iOS app which employs the HTTP/2).

However, when I tried uploading with HTTP2 by using Square's OkHttp, the proxy we used to test the bug (Charles) couldn't execute the requests, it resulted in IOExceptions.
Regarding your first comment - even if 409 is sent early, why do all the requests result in IOException in the next couple of minutes? (though the exact time for it to recover varies)

Answer (score 0):

For OkHttp use the debugging tools it provides to get additional data that explains what is going on, even if it's not immediately clear. Are you getting multiple routes back and the first one is slow and then gets marked as bad?

Event Logging - https://square.github.io/okhttp/events/

HTTP/2 Frame Logging (if you can enable) - https://square.github.io/okhttp/debug_logging/#http2-frame-logging

Run a debugger and capture stack traces of what is going on? Are the IO threads still reading and blocking the network?

Comment: Thank you Yuri for the response.
Regarding the frame logging, I'm not sure if I did it correctly but I've edited the post with what I see when debugging this with okhttp + http2.
BUT - this is using a proxy.  Without using the proxy the okhttp + http2 seems to work. 
So, what I edited the post with is with the proxy on.

Comment: Also, just wanted to mention that, at least by design, we don't do parallel requests. We wait for the upload request to finish (or fail) and then we open another one after some time if needed. Using HttpUrlConnection we call `disconnect` on the connection in the end. Using Okhttp we just use it basically like  `client.newCall(requestBuilder).execute().use { response ->
                val res = response.body?.string() ..` and don't call any closing method

Comment: And regadring the IO thread reading/blocking I am not sure how to check that. However, I did notice using the Proxy monitoring that sometimes after a failed request, when I try to send a new request, I see that the previous failed request is still "sending body..." (at least that's what the proxy is showing)

Comment: I wonder whether the client request is still being sent and causing some head of line blocking in either the client, or the proxy here.  You could try wrapping the request body such that it terminates forcibly once you know the request has failed or similar.

I don't think there Is a quick fix.  Try enabling the https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PrintEventsNonConcurrent.java and seeing if anything else shows up. Sorry!

Comment: I've updated the post with the PrintEventListener logs. Btw, I noticed that an image I was trying to upload many times, did get a 200 response eventually, and then the video file was stuck again.. So I'm assuming from the that it's now that the network isn't working, it's just very very slow. around 50KB/s

Comment: Yep - this looks like things are working but network is slow and requests timeout after 10 seconds.